# Using UnfoldingMaps to draw to PGraphics

Tags: java, processing, unfoldingmap

I want to use [Unfolding Maps](http://unfoldingmaps.org) to write to a PGraphics in Processing.

```
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.geo.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.*; 
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.*;

UnfoldingMap map;
PGraphics g;

void setup() {
    size(800, 600);
    map= new UnfoldingMap(this, new OpenStreetMap.OpenStreetMapProvider( ));
    map.zoomAndPanTo(new Location(52.5f, 13.4f), 10);    
    g = createGraphics(width, height);
}

void draw() {
    map.draw();
    g.beginDraw();
    //g.map.draw();no
    //map.draw(g);nope
    g.endDraw();
}
```

At `map.draw()` how do I make this print to the buffer `g`?

Answer (score 0):

Not the most straight-forward, but the current way of doing that would be

```
g.image(map.mapDisplay.getOuterPG().get(), 0, 0);
```

Comment: This does not seem to work:
Does `map.draw()` have to be within the main `draw()`?
Because changing `setup` and `draw` as below yields a blank screen:
`void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  map= new UnfoldingMap(this, new OpenStreetMap.OpenStreetMapProvider( ));
  map.zoomAndPanTo(new Location(52.5f, 13.4f), 10);    
  g = createGraphics(width, height);
  g.beginDraw();
  g.background(color(0,255,0));
  g.image(map.mapDisplay.getOuterPG().get(), 0, 0);
  g.endDraw();
  map.draw();

}
void draw() {

  image(g, 0, 0);
}`

Comment: Yes, all drawing in Processing has to be within draw(). You don't necessarily have to do that each frame, but it should not go into setup().